# How change the text on the Buttons generated automatically by the List Manager Item

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

change the text on the Buttons that were generated automatically by the List Manager Item Oracle APEX

assign a "Text Message" in Shared Components > Text Messages with names

APEX.LIST_MANAGER.BUTTON_ADD and
APEX.LIST_MANAGER.BUTTON_REMOVE

But without success

Answer (score 0):

I have not used list manager item type before but I did a test. Created a list manager item, then created the 2 text messages as you describe and as mentioned here: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/text-on-list-manager-buttons-1457.

This works fine for me. The button labels contain the values I have set in the text message:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the example provided.
I think my mistake was apparently  and using the Spanish language, since the language used is Spanish.
Grateful, it has helped me a lot

Comment: No problem. Consider [marking the question as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).